# Which indexes are necessary?

Tags: oracle, indexing, compound-index

If I have a table `TABLE_1` with, lets say 5 columns:

```
COL1    |   COL2    |   COL3    |   COL4    |   COL5
[line]
[line]
[...]
```

And there are two main queries I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE COL1 = 'X' and COL2 = 'Y'
```

And the other being:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE COL2 = 'Z'
```

Which indexes should I create? Creating one with columns `COL1` and `COL2` would index for both queries, or should I need another index just for `COL2` in order to have the second query faster?

thanks!

Comment: Hi there, Do you know how many distinct values would be in each column ? and which query is used the most often, as this will dictate which index/indexs to create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular B-tree index on `table_a(COL2, COL1)` could be used by both queries.

Having an index on `COL2` alone might be more efficient to retrieve rows using only a filter on this column but the additional index will use space and will slow down inserts (and updates if you ever update this column). It's a trade-off.

Comment: Worth noting that that index will NOT be used on "where COL1 = 'X'" because the column order in the index is wrong. For that you need an additional index. Either one for COL1 and another for COL2. Or (COL1,COL2) and COL2.

Comment: It may index skip scan the first column, if the cardinality is low, unless you know this you can't make an informed decision on which index/indexs to create.

Comment: @Björn: agreed, although the OP explicitely asks for only two queries (COL1, COL2) and (COL2)

Comment: Something else to consider; if `COL2` is not particularly selective and you have a significant amount of data, you may want to `COMPRESS` the index - `CREATE INDEX ... (COL2, COL1) COMPRESS 1`

Answer (score 4):

In his answer Vincent says this:

> "A regular B-tree index on table_a(COL2, COL1) could be used by both
>   queries."

The crucial word in that sentence is "could".  Because it is also true that such an index might not be used by either query.

Database indexing is a complicated and subtle subject.  There are [entire books written on the topic](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471719994.html).  Richard Foote has managed to maintain [a blog talking about nothing but Oracle Indexes](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/) (and David Bowie) for *years*.

We cannot give a definitive answer to the question without knowing some basic facts about the table: how many rows does it have?  How many distinct values of COL1 are there?  How many distinct values of COL2 are there?

So, let's look at some alternative answers.

If TABLEA contains only a dozen rows the chances are a Full Table Scan will be more efficient than any indexed read.

If COL2 is unique, the only index we need is `table_a(COL2)`

If COL2 is unselective (relatively few values compared to total number of rows) then the second query should use a Full Table Scan rather than an indexed read.

If COL2 is unselective but COL1 is highly selective (very many values compared to total number of rows, but not unique) then the first query should use an index on `table_a(COL2, COL1)`.

If COL2 is not particularly selective and COL1 is not particularly selective but the combination of the two is highly selective  then the first query should use an index on `table_a(COL2, COL1)`.  A Full Table Scan would be the preferred path for the second query.

If COL1 is unique it should have an index, which is what would be used in the first query, but it obviously wouldn't help in the second query.

Then there is the matter of NULLs, which futher complicate the issue.  NULLs are not indexed, except in composite indexes (and certain other special cases).

A truly complete answer would also address the matter of skew: if 90% of the rows in COL1 are '0' and the rest are highly selective then an index may or may not be useful.  We may need to generate histograms when we gather indexes, but they're only really helpful when a query uses literals rather than bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using composite index on col2 and col1. See the [Oracle concepts guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CHDJJIGA) for more details